# Transforming Excel 2010 documents?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am interested in writing an application that will take in an excel document of a specific format, massage the data and create a new Excel document that has different formatting.

I am curious if anyone can recommend a good place to start on this.

My first thought was to write something my self in C#.  I came across this tool on codeplex:

http://excelwrapperdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Usage%20-%20Example&referringTitle=Documentation

But it appears to only be for Excel 2007.

Is there a best practice for doing this type of thing for Excel 2010 documents?  Do I even need to program something custom to do this or does Excel offer something that might handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another nice library to modify Excel 2007/2010 documents (.xlsx) is [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). It gives you a nice object model on your spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

Excel files (.xslx) are archived XML files. They use 'Open XML', take a look here [MICROSOFT Open XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx)

That should get you going on the right path.